# When should I use Boost's lexical_cast? Is it a mechanism of last resort?

Tags: c++, boost, idioms, lexical-cast

Boost's `lexical_cast` converts numbers (or arbitrary objects) to strings and back. Should I try to use it more, say, instead of streaming things to `std::stringstream`s? Or is it more of a mechanism-of-last-resort?

Here's one example of two alternative approaches:

```
std::stringstream message;
message << "foo " << bar << ' ' << baz;
doSomething(message.str());
```

or

```
doSomething("foo " + lexical_cast<string>(bar) + " " + lexical_cast<string>(baz));
```

(but note my question is more general).

Comment: A third option for that example: `doSomething(boost::format("foo %1% %2%") % bar % baz));`

Comment: @aschepler Which the plethora of `%` renders pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Lexical cast doesn't not "mostly" convert numbers. It's a mechanisms for anything text-streamable. And yes, it depends. I freely use lexical_cast, but I don't hesitate to use std::stoi, std::to_string, Boost {Spirit|Format|Serializaton} depending on the use case.

In short: It's **not** a mechanism-of-last-resort. It's also not the *end-all-be-all* solution.

---

**Background**

- A common objection has been that lexical_cast would be slow. This is rarely the case (anymore) since it has been specialized for common primitive types
- The interface of lexical_cast is only appropriate when parsing should never/rarely fail; otherwise prefer an interface that reports input validation errors without exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should always use lexical_cast when converting string to a number, because without it you won't know whether it really was a number or not (bad lexical cast exception). The string stream doesn't throw anything and leaves the number uninitialized.

Comment: Hrm? You _can_ (and should) handle stream errors. This is a weak argument.

Comment: @einpoklum as sehe mentioned my argument isn't too strong. In your case I'd prefer the stringstream version

Comment: I'd say the fact that `boost::lexical_cast` can only report errors via an exception is a very strong argument _against_ it.  If you're dealing with user input, you don't want an exception; you want an error that you can test and handle locally.

Comment: @JamesKanze you can also handle the exception "somewhat" locally and besides you should always handle exceptions

Comment: Handling exceptions should only be done at the higher levels.  Handling them locally quickly leads to unreadable code; the whole point of exceptions is that you don't have to handle them locally.